# What is the key name of the child entries of 'Online Now' in Firebase Real-Time Database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: I am referring to this.]

I have tried "User ID" and "uid" but none of them work. I am trying to list all currently online users on my web site, that is why I need the key. I doubt the problem is with my code, but if someone could take a look that'd be much appreciated too:

```
firebaseDB.ref('Online Now').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
console.log(snapshot.child('uid').val())
```

Answer (score 0):

To list all users you need to loop through the snapshot:

```
firebaseDB.ref('Online Now').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
    console.log(userSnapshot.key)
  }
}
```

See the [Firebase documentation on reading lists of data using a `value` event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).

Comment: Missed that one! It wasn't in the API reference!

Comment: Your code didn't work. Didn't throw any errors, but the page that would execute it won't load.